# System command not running when called through cgi from Perl

Tags: html, perl, shell, cgi

I have been stuck for many days where I have a perl script. I have made a function in my CGI File which has some HTML content and a system command to execute a shell script.Then I have an href which calls the perl file which in turn calls the CGI function and shows the content on the browser. But everything is loading except the execution of system command in CGI. I tried to put this system command in my Perl File itself and on execution it is successfully executing the shell script from command line. But I wanted this to happen on a button click so I had to make a CGI call but still I am not able to call it.
I have been through many questions but I still am looking for the perfect answer.
Here is my code:
test1.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use Basecamp::UI;
use Basecamp::Dashboard;
use Basecamp::Info;

my $cgi = Basecamp::UI->new->cgi();
my $dashboard = Basecamp::Dashboard->new();
my @html = $cgi->tab_ext();

#push @html, '<div class="page">';
#push @html, newstuff();
#push @html, '</div>';
#print "Hello Hey";
#system( ' sh  /home/basecamplocal/Perforce/depot/qeutils/basecamp_dev/sample.sh ');

print $cgi->begin('Basecamp | ext', $dashboard), $cgi->begin_page();
print @html;
print $cgi->end_page(), $cgi->begin_footer(), $cgi->end_footer(), $cgi->end();
```

shell script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
#perl Basecamp.pl > log_sample.txt
touch log_sample.txt

echo "Good Day"
```

CGI File Function:

```
=item tab_ext()
======================================================================================

        DESC:   Generates appropriate tabs for About, about.pl.
        OUT:    Returns array of scalars with html to draw the tabs and any associated
                        subtabs.

======================================================================================
=cut
sub tab_ext
{
        my ($self) = @_;
        my $tab = $self->param('tab');
        my @tabs = ('<li><a href="test1.pl?tab=New">Status Restart</a></li>');
        my @subtabs = ();
        my @html = ();

        $tabs[0] = '<li class="selected"><a href="#">Status Restart</a></li>';

        @html = ('<ul id="tabs">', @tabs, '</ul>');

        push @html, ('<ul id="subtabs">', @subtabs, '</ul>');
        print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
        system("sh /full path to shell file /sample.sh ");


        return @html;

}
```

and I am calling the test1.pl file on a href call html.The whole html content from CGI is being displayed except the execution of shell script.
A helping hand would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you see http://perlmaven.com/running-external-programs-from-perl

Comment: Please be specific to the question. The link is all about the system command and I told you that it is running fine on independent execution.

Comment: There is no need to call `sh` explicitly (which may not be in the default `$PATH` when executing as a CGI script). Make `sample.sh` executable and you can just use `system('/full/path/to/sample.sh');  Be sure not to include a trailing space like you do now.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have permission issue. First check the permission of your `system.sh` program and parent directories. I think web user has no permission to execute the program.

Test code : `test.cgi`

Persmission : 755

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);
print header( -type => 'text/html' );
print <<EOF;

<title>Browser Page</title>
<body>
<div> Hellow </div>

EOF

my $command ="sh /tmp/abc.sh";
print "$command<br>";
system($command);
print "</body>";
```

code: `abc.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Good Day"
```

Output on the browser is

```
Hellow
sh /tmp/abc.sh 
Good Day
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I have given rwx permission to all for system.sh and why do I need to change permission for basecamp.pl.

Comment: you also need to check the permission of the parent directories. To check, you can keep your script in `/tmp` directory and then run. www-data has **tmp** directory permission(in ubuntu )

Comment: ok ! If I wouldn't have this permission should I be able to run it from terminal coz it is running fine with that but not from CGI call.

Comment: when you are running from terminal you have direct access to the program. and browser(www-data) need permission to your program. just think ,how browser will access your directory without your permission  `/home/basecamplocal/Perforce/depot/qeutils/basecamp_dev`

Comment: So which directory I should give permission to.I have given rwx permission to all files of basecamp_dev

Comment: First try to run your script from `tmp` directory to test and each directory in your file path need to execute level permission to the **www-data**.

Comment: how to locate www-data. I am not able to find it.

Comment: www-data is a group name. here is some information about it http://askubuntu.com/questions/244406/how-do-i-give-www-data-user-to-a-folder-in-my-home-folder  . I think it will help you

Comment: I have switched to root and trying the same. but still unsuccessful.

Comment: I didn't get what you did using root user. can you please explain

Comment: Root already has all permissions, so while running anything as a root there shouldnot be any permission problems. I just switched to root user and then simply went to browser and clicked on the href. but still shell script is not executing. I stored its exit code into a variable and exit code is 0 that means it is running is it ?

Comment: your cgi-script is running on the browser and root is not the user for the browser. consider browser as a external user.

Comment: Yes So what should I do . Please talk in terms of what I have to do rather what should I consider as I am new to this but I completely understand server and client analogy in this case. Please help.

Comment: have you tested your program by putting your script in /tmp directory?

Comment: Where can I find tmp directory. I used grep but I couldn't find the tmp directory rather found a tmp function.

Comment: what is your operating system . If its ubuntu just type `cd /tmp`

Comment: Yes I used the command and placed my sample.sh script at that place and then tried to run the same from root by restarting the server and clicked on the button. Still not able to execute sh. Please help.

Comment: Or you can suggest any other shell script which I can use so as to confirm that it is getting executed.